# javascript template litreral in side a react link tag to={} attribute

Tags: javascript, template-literals

```
<Link to={'${oldUrl}/${id}'} >
```

Hi, I am using template literal in a react app link tag and it is showing below error message please tell if anyone knows how to add it correctly?

> Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string

Comment: Look at @ClaretNnamocha answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
<Link to={`${oldUrl}/${id}`} >
```

And it should clear the error

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (`) for template literals, not quotes (') :

```
<Link to={`${oldUrl}/${id}`} >
```